# Bluetooth Manager in Linux Mint not working

Tags: linux-mint, bluetooth

I have a problem with bluetooth on my Linux device:

[image: Bluetooth problem]

- I did some troubleshooting and reinstalled `bluetooth` and `blueman`.
- I then did the following:

  ```shell
  /etc/init.d/bluetooth start
  /etc/init.d/bluetooth status
  ```

  but bluetooth was still not active.
- So I also did following:

  ```shell
  sudo modprobe btusb
  ```

  and started bluetooth again and it was active.

But after that, I couldn't start the bluetooth manager.

Comment: you did load the kernel bluetooth usb module. Do you have a bluetooth usb adapter and is it connected?  output of ```lsusb``` ?, output of ```systemctl status bluetooth.service```?

Comment: @Schmaehgrunza If i use "systemctl status bluetooth.service". I see that bluetooth is running. Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Fri 2024-03-29 16:59:49 CET; 21min ago
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8).  But I can't see it on rfkill or neither connect something.